# C: Writing a loop to print the alphabet between two characters

Tags: c

I've been given the pretty simple task of writing a program that will take two characters and then print the letters inbetween them using a for() loop.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
char a, b;

printf("\nEnter the first character: ");
scanf("%c", &a);

printf("\nEnter the second character: ");
scanf("%c", &b);

for(char i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    printf("%c ", i);
}

return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I am prompted to enter the first character correctly but when I press enter it only runs the next printf() and then terminates.

No errors or warnings or anything on compilation. Another similar question I found that was apparently solved does not work for me either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &b);` --> `scanf(" %c", &b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consume the `\n` in `stdin` left by first `scanf`.

Fastest fix

```
scanf(" %c", &b);
```

The space before `%c` tells to `scanf` to ignore all whitespaces before to read the `char`.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, by pressing enter, you would enter the second character, which would most probably (depending on the environment) start with a numeric value of `13`, which would be smaller than any letter, so the loop's body is executed only once.